# How can I export and import ID property as json? (to make preset file)

Tags: python, export, import

I think it should be simple, but could not find correct way ore related document then hope to know way.

Now I have active armature as "amt" , and it have many ID properties for shape keys and drive some bones.  eg  amt["prop1"] = 1.0, amt["prop2"] = 0.2 etc,,

by bpy, I can get amt ID property keys and values of current frame,  which I only need to export, as python dictionary.

eg  preset = {"prop1":1.0, "prop3" :0.2,,,}

Now I hope to export the dictionary as json, 
then import the saved json , and apply these ID property values for current active armature, when I need. (of course it have same ID property keys)
 (I prefer to export as json,,)

Comment: You might want to change the word *ID* to *Key* since in Python, ID is a unique special thing which is different from dictionary key in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code get some data from Blender scene, save them as Python dict and write a JSON file. Then read that file and uses the inner data:

```
import bpy
import json
import os

# 1 - Export data as JSON file

# dict with all your data
dict = {
    "name": "Cube 1",
    "material": "Cube MAT"
}

# encode dict as JSON 
data = json.dumps(dict, indent=1, ensure_ascii=True)

# set output path and file name (set your own)
save_path = 'E:\\'
file_name = os.path.join(save_path, "export_data.json")

# write JSON file
with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(data + '\n')


# 2 - Import data from JSON file

# read JSON file
with open(file_name, 'r') as fp:
    data_file = json.load(fp)

# get data
cube_name = data_file['name']
cube_material = data_file['material']

print(cube_name + ', ' + cube_material)
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation of why use `json.dumps()` instead of `json.dump()`? I know the later is seldom used in practice, but still don't know why.

Comment: J.Aron Really thanks , it is what I need I think. I am now edit blender python template with compare your answer for json. and I use ID properties of armature obj, not use bpy.props, then your answer much for my question.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, use `json` module: [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

You will need to handle the conversion between properties and Dictionary by yourself, maybe two `bpy.type.Operator` with a `PropertiesGroup`.

And *load/save* the dictionary by `json.dump()` and `json.load()`